# how to design class method that returns two different return type?

Tags: java, methods, return-value, return-type

A subclass having small logic and it's return Boolean true/false or error message but in case of any exception it catch into an same class and error message just for intimation to the upper class which used to show error message in UI.i'm n't able to think about how to manage subclass return value because if subclass works successfully it return Boolean true/false,but in case of error it return String error message this point i found problem of two different type of return value from method.please help me how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options return an object

```
class Status {
   Boolean succesful;
   String errorText;
}
```

or throw an Exception if an error occurs

```
throw new Exception( errorText );
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you return String error code? Just throw your exception(maybe, wrapped in some other one) and receive it upper.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear.
From my understanding, you should return a Boolean or an Exception.
You should set your error message in the exception (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String%29).
You can also return different exceptions if you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your subclass return a variable of type Object you can check its data type higher up.

```
//Success
Object object = new Boolean();

//Fail
Object object = new String();

if(object instanceOf Boolean) {
//Do something
} else if(object instanceOf String) {
//Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Functional Java's Either class. It is an implementation to hold one of two values.

[Either](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/index.html)